# Bootstrap modal not updating modal content

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap, forms, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to create a table of models with a button next to them which opens a modal and has the same model row in form view. The table is being populated correctly, but the n number of *bootstrap modals* being created only hold the first iterable model value. Is it because bootstrap loads the content of the modals only once when the page is rendered ? What do I do to solve the problem ? Should I run a function to update the modal content according to the model data it has ??

Feel free to ask any more clarifications.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% block content %}
    <table>
        {% for item in data %}

            <tr>
                <th>From</th>
                <th>To</th>
                <th>Weight</th>
                <th>Length</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Material Type</th>
                <th>Number of Trucks</th>
                <th>Loading Time</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>{{ item.From }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.To }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.Weight }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.Length }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.Type }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.MaterialType }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.Numberoftrucks }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.Loadingtime }}</td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Bid
                        now! for id {{ item.id }} </button>
                </td>
                {#        {% endfor %}#}


                <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span
                                        aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">

                                <input class="form-control" id="disabledInput" type="text"
                                       placeholder="Disabled input here..." value="{{ item.To }}" disabled>
                                <input class="form-control" id="disabledInput" type="text"
                                       placeholder="Disabled input here..." value="{{ item.From }}" disabled>
                                <input class="form-control" id="disabledInput" type="text"
                                       placeholder="Disabled input here..." value="{{ item.Weight }}" disabled>
                                <input class="form-control" id="disabledInput" type="text"
                                       placeholder="Disabled input here..." value="{{ item.Length }}" disabled>
                                <input class="form-control" id="disabledInput" type="text"
                                       placeholder="Disabled input here..." value="{{ item.Type }}" disabled>
                                <input class="form-control" id="disabledInput" type="text"
                                       placeholder="Disabled input here..." value="{{ item.MaterialType }}" disabled>
                                <input class="form-control" id="disabledInput" type="text"
                                       placeholder="Disabled input here..." value="{{ item.Numberoftrucks }}" disabled>
                                <input class="form-control" id="disabledInput" type="text"
                                       placeholder="Disabled input here..." value="{{ item.Loadingtime }}" disabled>
                                <input class="form-control" id="disabledInput" type="text"
                                       placeholder="Disabled input here...">Bid
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can fix it by add `model.pk` to the modal `id`

in the button

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal"
     data-target="#myModal{{ item.id }}">
    Bid now! for id {{ item.id }}
</button>
```

and in the

```
 <div class="modal fade"
      id="myModal{{ item.id }}"
      tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
```

other solution is create js function to load new data to each time as you activate the modal.

Comment: Thanks! This works just fine! I had another doubt,  I want to render a form in that 
 modal based on another model, so how do I go about doing that? Or should I post another question ?

Comment: i think you should try to find solution your self. And if you catch any troubles then post another question.

Comment: @BearBrown The activation of modal will be done as the Id is populated right? I did as you mentioned for Html files and in js i created a function which will populate the data to  the modal content and its id. The data gets populated, but the modal doesnt open.

Comment: is there any errors in the browser's console? if you really need a help, i think is to be better to create a question with more details of your code.

Comment: @BearBrown - No errors in the console. And my problem is exactly same as this question. If i create new, then people would mark it as duplicate of this question...

Comment: try to search for a typo, any way without your code it is to hard to help.